# How to get current month in google appscript in the format SEP 1 - 15?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am trying to Send an email mentioning the time period like
MONTH 1 - 15 or MONTH 16- "END OF MONTH 28/29/30/31" in an email subject, body(which is created using HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('file.html')

sending email before 15th of a month, i want to fetch date as "MONTH 1-15" and sending email after 15th of a month, i want to fetch date as "MONTH 16-EOM".

For sending the email, I would setup an auto trigger on desired date like 14th or 28-31st

Comment: The same way you get it in JavaScript. new Date().getMonth() which is zero based.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `new Date().getDate()`, which will return the day and from here do your logic and format the date.

For reference see the link:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate